# How do I copy a directory as well containing files with Puppet

Tags: puppet

I am looking to copy a directory its files using Puppet.
The directory, as well as most files/subdirectories, will already exist at the time of copy.

The copy is working for new files and removing files that are not in the source, but existing files are not being updated.

For example, `dir/index.html` will be created if it doesn't exist, but will not be updated even if the source contains an update version of the file.

Looking for help as to how I can tell puppet to copy/overwrite all the files in the directory. Wasn't sure if I should be using something like `force` to achieve this.

```
    file { "${directory}":
        ensure  => directory,
        owner   => $user,
        group   => "$user",
        mode    => '0755',
        recurse => true,
        source  => "puppet:///modules/role/${directory}",
    } ->
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation for the `file` resource](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/types/file.html#file-attribute-recurse), your configuration is correct and should replace files which don't match the source. This behaviour is configured by setting `recurse` to `true`.

I'd note the `force` option only applies to directories. It is the `replace` attribute which applies to files. Given that files aren't being replaced, is it possible that `replace => false` has been set as a default attribute for file resources somewhere in your manifests? A default setting would look like

```
File {
  replace => false,
}
```

As mentioned by John in the comments, you can override a default by explicitly setting `replace` in your file resource:

```
file { $directory:
        ensure  => directory,
        owner   => $user,
        group   => $user,
        mode    => '0755',
        recurse => true,
        replace => true,
        source  => "puppet:///modules/role/${directory}",
    }
```

Comment: ... and the OP could override such a resource default by explicitly specifying `replace => true` in their `file` resource.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be noted as such.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately I could not comment on the answer above.

I think the "mode => ..." line should be removed, as it will result in ALL files having that mode instead of the original one.